# Matrix Lie group counter-example: $e^X$ in the Lie group, but $X$ is not in the Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

What's an example of a Lie group $G$ and matrix $X$ such that $e^X \in G$ but $x \notin \mathfrak{g}$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the associated Lie algebra?

This is the same as problem 2.10 in Bryan Hall's "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations: An Elementary Introduction."

Comment: Take $G$ to be trivial...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take $H = \{ \pm I\}$ that has trivial Lie algebra because it is a finite group. The matrix

$$X = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -\pi \\ \pi & 0 \end{array}\right)$$

is such that $e^X = \left(\begin{array}{cc} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array}\right)$ but $X$ is not zero and hence is not in the Lie algebra.

Comment: (For what it's worth, Maple says that $e^X = -I$, but you can just change $H$ to accommodate it.  In order to see why your answer *must* be wrong, note that the nontrivial element of $H$ has determinant $-1$, so is in a different connected componenet of $GL_2$ than $I$.  In particular, it cannot be $e^X$ for any $X$).

Comment: @JasonDeVito I have edited my answer. I messed up before :D

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realize what a simple question this is until I read your clear answer.

Comment: ¿But is there any example with a matrix Lie group which is not trivial as in this example (that is, not a finite grpup, and with a Lie algebra of dimension larger than zero?

Comment: @kjetil: take the direct product with any nontrivial Lie algebra / Lie group.

Answer (score 9):

Old question, but another example with nontrivial Lie algebra: Take $G = \mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb C)$, with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb C) = \left\{X \in M_n(\mathbb C) : \mathrm{tr}(X) = 0\right\}$. Then $X := 2\pi i I_n$ does not lie in $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb C)$, but $e^X = I_n \in \mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb C)$.

Comment: Nice one, thank you!